# When running a simple streamlit app with pickles to load, I am getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'" Error

Tags: python, pickle

The code below is how I am loading the pickled files (Note: These pickled files are made correctly so no problem there, unless the code is needed too).

```
    import streamlit as st
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    
    Pickle1 = open("../Backend/pickle1.pkl", 'rb')
    Pickle2 = open("../Backend/pickle2.pkl", 'rb')
    p1 = pickle.load(Pickle1)
    p2 = pickle.load(Pickle2)
    

    st.title('App')
```

I saw the other solution in StackOverflow but the solution states that the pandas.core.indexes.numeric is not contained in the package but mine does (after running
import pandas.core.indexes as i, I did not get any error). I also tried upgrading pandas but it's on the latest version, and I tried asking chatGPT but it gave me the same solution: to upgrade pandas. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue raised [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53300), which might be helpful.
If the pickle file is generated with `pandas<2`, there might be issues reading it with `pandas>2`. Alternatively, you can use the `pandas.read_pickle` method as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from myclass import myClass

mc = pd.read_pickle("file_name.pkl")
dict(mc)
```

where `myclass.py` is a custom Python file as follows:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, thing, df):
    self.thing=thing
    self.df=df
  def __iter__(self):
    yield "thing", self.thing
    yield "df", self.df
```

Comment: Yep, I did the pd.read_pickle() method and now it works. Thank you for the solution :)